# _io.TextIOWrapper Error trying to open a file

Tags: python

I'm working with TSV file (here below `my_file`) and trying to write it down to another *temp* file with a random *ID* (here below `my_temp_file`)and this is what I wrote:

```
def temp_generator():
    while True:
        my_string = 'tmp' + str(random.randint(1,1000000000))
        if not os.path.exists(my_string):
            return my_string

randomID = temp_generator()

my_temp_file = open('mytemp_'+randomID + '.tsv', 'w')
with open(my_file, 'r+') as mf:
    for line in mf:
        my_temp_file.write(line)
my_temp_file.close()
mf.close()
```

The output is something like:

> mytemp_1283189.tsv

Now I'd like to work with `my_temp_file.tsv` in order to modify its content and rename it but if I try to open it with:

```
with open (my_temp_file.tsv, 'r') as mtf:
    data = mtf.read()
    print(data)
```

This is what I obtain:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

What can I do?

Comment: Aren't you missing quotes on `my_temp_file.tsv`? Also, that's not the correct file name with the number in it. Why exactly do you need a random numbered file?

Comment: Why don't you simply copy an initial file as `from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)` instead of your `my_temp_file.write(line)` ?

Comment: `my_temp_file` is a variable that refers to a file handle (which has been closed).  Instead to open it again you need to pass the _name_ of the file to `open`.

Comment: Did you do research as required in [ask]? It's as simple as [search for the error-message here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+expected+str%2C+bytes+or+os.PathLike+object%2C+not+_io.TextIOWrapper) ️

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

The pattern `handle = open(path)`
is opening a file at path from `path` and returns the handle assigned to `handle`. You can use `handle` to `.write`, `.read`, or `.close`. But you can not open it again or use it as input to `open` - which expects a Path-like object, e.g. a filename.

#### Fixed

```py
def temp_generator():
    while True:
        my_string = 'tmp' + str(random.randint(1,1000000000))
        if not os.path.exists(my_string):
            return my_string

randomID = temp_generator()

# copy from input (my_file) to output, a random temp file (my_temp_file)
my_temp_file = 'mytemp_' + randomID + '.tsv'
with open(my_temp_file, 'w') as mtf:
    with open(my_file, 'r+') as mf:  #  my_file is supposed to be a Path-like object
        for line in mf:
            mtf.write(line)
# since with..open used, no close needed (auto-close!)

# modify output (content and rename the file)
# remember: my_temp_file is holding a Path or filename 
with open(my_temp_file, 'r') as mtf:  # open the file again
    data = mtf.read()
    print(data)
```

See also:

- [[Solved] Python TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper](https://flutterq.com/python-typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-_io-textiowrapper/)
- Python documentation about `TextIOWrapper`: [io — Core tools for working with streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Answer (score -1):

Your error is here, assuming you are actually using `open(my_temp_file`

```
my_temp_file = open('mytemp_'+randomID + '.tsv', 'w')
with open(my_file, 'r+') as mf:
```

You've already opened the file, so you shouldn't open it again using the file handle as the parameter. You should prefer only using the `with` way of opening files, too

For example

```
my_temp_file = 'mytemp_'+randomID + '.tsv'
with open(my_temp_file, 'r+') as mf:
```

Even then, if you're going to eventually rename the file, just make it the name you want from the start

Comment: `my_file` is the original TSV, `my_temp_file` is the temp file I'm writing. They're not the same file.

Comment: Okay, well, as the error says, you need to give the open function a string, not a file object

Comment: I think you recognized and explained the issue here, but the logic and intention for OPs code is misconceived as far as I understood. Might need more clarification before we can propose a proper solution.